# Magento 2 - invalid form key (add/delete from cart)

Tags: magento2, php, cart, cache, form-key

I have serious problems with custom Magento 2 theme and (probably) formkey cashing. I have 2 views of exactly same e-shop.

```
 - View 1: Luma Theme
 - View 2: Custom Theme (Luma child) - overriding layouts, phtml, styles and javascripts
```

If cache is enabled and flushed everything -> adding/deleting from car works properly. After several minutes specified actions in View 2 (Custom theme) returns `302 status code` and Magento redirects user to /cart page.

Now i discovered 3 ways how to "fix" this issue.

1. Flush cache - only temporary solution for few minutes.
2. Delete formKey validation from Magento core - totally inappropriate.
3. Disable cache - affects performance.

I'm struggling with this problem couple of days and I will be glad for any advice.

Comment: You're trying `localhost` as the top level domain?

Comment: No, tld is eu or dev. View 1 with Luma works propertly.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 - `invalid form key` occurs before of 2 reasons.

1) check your view source page, generated form_key and passing form_key are same. if not same need to fix it.

2) increase `php_value max_input_vars` `75000`. Check your error log surely max_input_vars reached error will through.

Hope it will helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with magento 2.3, where **Add to Cart** button refreshed the page instead of adding anything in cart. where as website was working properly in **Private Browsing** on a custom theme.

**Solutions Didn't Worked:**

- Change max_input_var=10000
- max_input_time = 600
- max_execution_time = 3600
- Flush cache

**Solution Worked for me:**

In Configuration >> Web, I:

- change **baseURL** from **http://www.domain.com** to **http://domain.com**
- change **Secure Base URL** from **https://www.domain.com** to **https://domain.com**
- Flush cache

I am not sure if its a reliable fix or a temporary, but it resolved the issue for now.